# Polymorphic relationship trouble in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, polymorphism

Ok So i am trying to get my head around polymorphism in laravel.

I'm building a site that has 2 different types of users (recruiters, candidates)

They both have some common details which i have created in a user table:

| id | Username | email | password | detailable_id | detailable_type

The rest of the details are going to be very different so i thought i could use polymorphism to help me with this. so i created 2 more tables:

recruiters -> to contain recruiter specific details

candidates -> to contain candidate specific details

I have models for each table

user model:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password'];

    public function detailable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Candidate model:

```
class Candidate extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
    return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'detailable');
    }

}
```

Recruiter model:

```
class Recruiter extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\User', 'detailable');
    }
}
```

So I did it this way as most tutorials explain it this way (most are explaining how comments can be added onto different objects)
This however does not work how i need it to. In this i can do something like `$user = App\Recruiter::find($recruiter_id)->user` to get the user if i have the recruiter id or object. But what i ideally want to be able to do is to say `$details = App\User::find('$user_id')->details` or  `Auth::user()->details`

I really cannot wrap my head around how i would make this work, can anybody help? Or maybe tell me that this cant be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel quite stupid as i have just found the answer in Laravels documentation. You can do what i require with this setup, all i have to do is type `Auth::user()->detailable` and this returns the details for the user